# Compare string to bytes that works in both Python 2 and 3

Tags: python, string

What is the best way to compare a string object to a bytes object that works in both Python 2 and Python 3?  More generally, how does one write a Python 2 and Python 3 compatible comparison of two objects that may each be a string, bytes, or Unicode object?  Assume that the data is encoded (in the case of bytes) or encodable (in the case of strings) with UTF-8.

The problem is that `"asdf" == b"asdf"` is True in Python 2 and False in Python 3.

Meanwhile, one cannot blindly encode or decode objects, since strings in Python 2 have both `encode` and `decode` methods, but strings in Python 3 just have encode methods.

Finally, `isinstance(obj, bytes)` returns True for any non-unicode string in Python 2 and returns True for only bytes objects in Python 3.

---

**Note to moderators:**  There has been some confusion as to why this question is needed (i.e. what practical problem this is solving).  The particular problem that that motivated this question was how to interface with a library that changed the type of its return (from string to bytes) between Python 2 and Python 3.  I needed a solution that was compatible with both to facilitate upgrading the codebase in question from one to the other, though this could also be relevant to downstream libraries that still want to have Python 2 compatibility.  I didn't need to do anything with the return other than test for equality against known payloads, hence the question just being about equality testing.

Comment: Why are you comparing them in the first place?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It's not relevant to the question.  The situation where I am running into this is in comparing the output of a digital signature library with a key on a web request; one is a string while the other is a bytestring.  However, this question was an attempt to capture the more general situation, since I haven't found any material on this.

Comment: But this is not terribly useful in a general situation. Normally you'd decode the bytes to text before comparing them.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Whether or not that is true, when I found myself looking for this question, it did not exist.  I would like it to exist in the off chance that anyone else encounters a similar situation

Comment: Neither a string nor a `bytes` object can "be" UTF-8. UTF-8 is a *rule for converting* from one to another. Saying "assume the string is UTF-8" is like writing out `nineteen` in cursive and then saying "assuming the integer is octal".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel UTF-8 is an encoding for character data, not a rule for conversion.  The python encode/decode methods take an encoding format as an argument because there are many options for what encoding the input or output will be in.  Bytes objects can absolutely be in UTF-8, as they have an encoding when you make them.  Meanwhile, strings can be UTF-8 compliant or not.  Specifying that a string is valid if encoded in UTF-8 is also absolutely a meaningful statement.

Comment: @Zags Yes, UTF-8 is an encoding. "A rule for conversion" is **what that means** - to encode is to convert data from one form to another. "The python encode/decode methods take an encoding format as an argument because there are many options for what encoding the input or output will be in." They take the name of an encoding, as a string, and then apply the corresponding rule. "Bytes objects can absolutely be in UTF-8, as they have an encoding when you make them." This is nonsense - you can create them in other ways besides converting from string, and once you have converted, it is just data.

Comment: The encoding is not a property of the object that you end up with; it's a property of *one possible process* that you use to *create* the object.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The question is about comparing data between types.  The encoding is an ancillary detail.  If you want to edit the question to be technically correct with regard to how it talks about encodings, be my guest.  However, closing a question that has this many views and upvotes because you disagree with a particular detail seems like a misuse of the site's tools.

Comment: No, I voted to close the question because it isn't clear what *practical problem is solved* with this approach. A major, explicit goal of 3.x was to **stop** inappropriately treating `bytes` as though they were already text. Code which treats `b'foo'` and `'foo'` as "equal" is inviting bugs.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The practical problem is that many libraries changed the type of their output between Python 2 and Python 3, and writing a downstream library required having compatibility with both.  This question is less useful given Python 2 is nearly 3 years past end of life, but the problem still existed at the point at which this question was active.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is there a more appropriate closed question notice that has to do with deprecated technologies?  Clearly a number of people found this question clear and helpful given it got 9 upvotes, 2 bookmarks, and at one person beyond me posted an  appropriate answer.

Comment: I will not discuss the matter further here. Please take it to Meta.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel this has been asked and answered on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280360/2800876.  Questions about use-cases for deprecated technologies are absolutely valid and on-topic.

Comment: That does not address my objection to the question. I already explained myself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I already edited the question to clarify it's use of the term "encoding" to be more technically rigorous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In both Python 2 and Python 3, anything that is an instance of `bytes` has a decode method.  Thus, you can do the following:

```
def compare(a, b, encoding="utf8"):
    if isinstance(a, bytes):
        a = a.decode(encoding)
    if isinstance(b, bytes):
        b = b.decode(encoding)
    return a == b
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether you're using Python 2 or 3 and act accordingly:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    text_type = unicode
else:
    text_type = str

if isinstance(obj, text_type):
    result = obj.encode('utf-8')
else:
    result = obj
```